# Can't remember my Apple ID

Tags: apple-id, keychain, game-center

I remember my nickname for my Game Center but I don't remember what the Apple ID was for it is there a way to retrieve this information

Answer (score 1):

The only way to find out your Apple ID is by visiting https://iforgot.apple.com and clicking 'I forgot my Apple ID'. Enter in the forms there as best as you can and if there's any Apple ID tied to your information it should come up.

Comment: If you don't know the emailadress either perhaps you can find it in the App Store app. Open it on your iOS device and scroll to the bottom on `featured` page for example, and if needed use `iForgot` there too.